# Sharepoint 2013 Content Search vs. Javascript CSOM

Tags: javascript, search, client-object-model

I did what this page teaches:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SharePoint-2013-Querying-a629b53b

It works, but the thing is that I used the same KQL query in a content search webpart and I have something missing. I changed a bit the code to get me all site collections. I have 5 sites, two are projects web templates. The content search web part gives me all my sites, but the project ones are missing from my code!

Here's my query:

```
"contentclass:STS_Site -Path:http://mysite.server.com -Path:http://portal.server.com"
```

The query gives me all sites from my others webapps, like intranet.server.com, etc.

Comments are appreciated!

---

Just a few more info:

[image]

[image]

[image]

My Code:

```
var ctx;
var web;
var results;

function test() {
    var queryStr = "contentclass:STS_Site -Path:http://mysite.ubi.com -Path:http://portal.ubi.com"
    ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var keywordQuery = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(ctx);
    keywordQuery.set_queryText(queryStr);
    var searchExecutor = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor(ctx);
    results = searchExecutor.executeQuery(keywordQuery);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySuccess, onQueryFail);
 }

 function onQuerySuccess() {
    $("#searchResults").append('<table>');

    $.each(results.m_value.ResultTables[0].ResultRows, function () {
       $("#searchResults").append('<tr>');
       $("#searchResults").append('<td>' + this.Title + '</td>');
       $("#searchResults").append('<td>' + this.Author + '</td>');
       $("#searchResults").append('<td>' + this.Write + '</td>');
       $("#searchResults").append('<td>' + this.Path + '</td>');
       $("#searchResults").append('</tr>');
    });

    $("#searchResults").append('</table>');
}

function onQueryFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Query failed. Error:' + args.get_message());
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btn").click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       test();
    });

});
```

PS.: I did a full crawl and nothing changed. Well, it worked for the document center, but not for the project sites (PROJECTSITE#0) PS2.: I also checked if fiddler to make sure it wasn't the code, but the response is really different in each of the cases.

Comment: So, the CSWP gives you all 5 sites with this query, but JSOM gives you 3 sites with the same KQL query ?

Comment: Is your code running as the same user as your CSWP?

Comment: @PhilippeLavoie, Yes, I'll try to put some prints of the code and the results here.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott, I'm not sure. My code and the CSWP are running in the same session, but I know that it doesn't mean they're running in the same account. That happens with services for exemple, but JSOM... Can you give me some tips on how to know this for sure? Thanks!

Comment: @Ubi Did you set your Search permissions to QueryAsUserIgnoreAppPrincipal as specified in your reference article? If so, the search query should be as the current user

Comment: I would start by comparing the properties of the different search approaches, Display Duplicates and Security are two things to look at.

Comment: @Louis, no, because what I'm doing isn't an app. I don't know where to set this in pure javascript. I'm only doing a script which will run in the master page to create a custom navigation.

Comment: @Ubi Ah in that case its running as the current user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, you know what, my top head scratcher when I am missing results in SharePoint search is that darn "trim duplicates" option (which I think is ON by default)

SharePoint may very well be considering your pj and pj1 results too similar to another one in the list.

Try adding:

```
// Set Trim Duplicates to False
keywordQuery.set_trimDuplicates(false);
```

Also see this link for lots of good info on Search CSOM:
https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2014/01/sharepoint-2013-search-javascript-csom-primer/

Comment: It works! Thank you Louis! Thanks for the link as well! Tons of good info there!